# Looking for a "clever" argument for a $q$-series identity

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, enumerative-combinatorics

Consider the below $q$-series identity. One of the things I like about this expansion is how nicely the difference on the left hand side factors to the right hand side of the equation.

$$\prod_{k\geq1}(1+q^k)^3-\prod_{k\geq1}(1+q^{3k})
=3q\prod_{n\geq1}(1+q^n)(1+q^{9n})^2(1+q^n+q^{2n}+\cdots+q^{8n}).$$

I have a "not-so-neat" proof, so

> **QUESTION.** Can you provide a "nifty" justification? *Caveat: you decide what is "nifty"*.

Comment: The element in the first product is obtained performing this sequence of operations: 1) raise $q$ to the power $k$ 2) add $1$ 3) raise to the cube, while the element in the second is obtained swapping steps 2) and 3), so perhaps you can try to analyse the structure of a commutator. Notice also that in the second case, raising to the cube commutes to raising to the power $k$, so the identity should respect this symmetry.

Comment: Perhaps you can establish a link to the subgroups of the cyclic group of order $9$, which, if I'm not mistaken, contains as many normal subgroups as factors in the RHS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a proof that indicates a systematic method for proving such identities. Let $\eta(z) = q^{1/24} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{n})$, with $q = e^{2 \pi i z}$. The identity you state in the equation is the same as
$$
  \frac{\eta^{3}(2z)}{\eta^{3}(z)} - \frac{\eta(6z)}{\eta(3z)} = 3 \frac{\eta(2z) \eta^{2}(18z)}{\eta^{2}(z) \eta(9z)}.
$$
Replacing $z$ with $2z$ and multiplying by $\eta(2z) \eta(4z) \eta^{2}(6z)$ gives the equivalent
$$
  \frac{\eta^{4}(4z) \eta^{2}(6z)}{\eta^{2}(2z)} - \eta(2z) \eta(4z) \eta(6z) \eta(12z) = 3 \frac{\eta^{2}(4z) \eta^{2}(6z) \eta^{2}(36z)}{\eta(2z) \eta(18z)}.$$
Results about $\eta(z)$ in [Gordon and Hughes - Multiplicative properties of $\eta$-products. II](https://doi.org/10.1090/conm/143/01008), and Ligozat - Courbes modulaires de genre 1 ([MR](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=422158)) guarantee that each of the three terms in the above equation are in the space of weight $2$ cusp forms for the group $\Gamma_{0}(72)$. This space has dimension $5$, and if $f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} q^{n}$ is a function in the space with $a_{1} = a_{2} = \dotsb = a_{7} = 0$, it follows that $f = 0$. It suffices to verify that the coefficients of $q^{1}$ through $q^{7}$ are the same for the two sides of the equivalent identity above.

Comment: Since Wikipedia might change over time, I inlined what seemed to be the two references you, umm, referenced.

Comment: The eta-product identity you exhibit is equivalent to the first 
identity on level 18 in my "Dedekind eta-product
identity database" and is listed as $\,t_{18,5,18}.\,$
It references proofs from two sources. The first is
by Bruce Berndt, "Ramanujan's Notebooks", Part III,
page 349, Entry 2 (ii). The second is by Borwein,
Browein and Garvan, "Some Cubic Modular Identities
of Ramanujan", Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. v. 343 n. 1
(1994) pp. 35-47 on page 41.

Comment: @Somos: Thank you for the references. Looking at the BBG paper, page 41, equation (2.16), I see a factor of $2$ while in the problem above we've a factor of $3$. How do you reconcile these?

Comment: The leading coefficient of the $q$-series expansion of $\,\theta_2(q)\,$ is $2$.

Comment: @Somos: I have the feeling the arguments in one or both of these sources might be more along the lines of a "clever" proof that the OP had in mind that what I've supplied. I'd encourage you to turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @JeremyRouse: I enjoyed your solution, no doubt. At the same time, I would be happy to see if Somos can bring in another of the sort.

Comment: @Somos Hi Michael, i noticed some time ago that your eta identities database was no more online. Is it back at a different site?

Comment: @Wolfgang Please send me email for these kind of questions. In any case, I am open to web hosting alternatives. For now you can use the Wayback Machine to access the archived contents.